# Warnings of Pointer to array of matrices In ANSI C GCC C90

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-to-array

I'm having strange warnings in Linux.
In Visual Studio on Windows, the code compiles and works well but I need to compile it with GCC c90 I get these warnings:

I've initialized the matrix like this:

```
typedef float mat[4][4];
```

Now i want to create an array of matrices:

```
mat MAT_A = { 0 };
mat MAT_B = { 0 };
mat MAT_C = { 0 };
mat *matrices[3] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};
```

I've declared the function:

```
void get_input(mat** matrices);
```

and use it:

```
get_input(&matrices);
```

The code is working well but I need to compile it with gcc c90.
And I get this warnings:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]  
mat *(*matrices)[3] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};                     
                       ^~~~~
```

and

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_input’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    flag = get_input(&matrices);
                     ^
```

Comment: Note that `mat *matrices[3] = { &MAT_A, &MAT_B, &MAT_C };` compiles OK with GCC set fussy for both C90 and C11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to this typedef declaration

```
typedef float mat[4][4];
```

arrays declared like

```
mat MAT_A = { 0 };
```

are implicitly converted to its first element in this declaration

```
mat *matrices[3] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};
```

of the type `float( * )[4]`. But the variable matrices is declared as having the element type `float ( * )[4][4]`. These types are not compatible.

That is in fact you have the following declaration

```
float ( *matrices[3] )[4][4] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};
```

You should declare the array eother like

```
float ( *matrices[3] )[4] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};
```

In this case the function should be declared like

```
void get_input( float ( ** matrices)[4] );
```

and called like

```
get_input( matrices );
```

or like

```
mat *matrices[3] = { &MAT_A, &MAT_B, &MAT_C };
```

in the last case the function is called like

```
get_input( matrices );
```

Also the function `get_input` declared like

```
void() get_input(mat** matrices);
```

actually is equivalent to

```
void() get_input( float ( ** matrices )[4][4]);
```

But in this call of the function

```
get_input(&matrices);
```

the argument has the type

```
float( * ( * ) [3])[4][4]
```

Comment: Hey Vlad. thanks for the fast answer.
So how do I need to change the code?

the matrices declaration to make it work right?

Comment: @RuslanVer See my updated post.

Comment: Thanks!! works for both ways, very good explanation.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The `mat *matrices[3]` is an array of 3 pointers to `mat`. So one needs to initialize it with *pointers to mat*.

```
mat *matrices[3] = {&MAT_A, &MAT_B, &MAT_C};
```

Moreover, when calling `get_input(&matrices);`, the `&matrices` is a pointer to an array of 3 pointers to `mat`. This is not what `get_input()` expects what is a pointer to a pointer to `mat`. Just use:

```
get_input(matrices);
```

The expression `matrices` is transformed to a pointer to its first element which is a pointer to `mat`. As result, the type of the expression is a pointer to a pointer to `mat`, exactly what `get_input` expects.

Now the code compiles without a warning. See https://godbolt.org/z/84qd4rrnx

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mat *matrices[3] = {MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C};
```

to

```
mat *matrices[3] = {&MAT_A, &MAT_B, &MAT_C};
```